# Is there a way to determine if a given image shows gradient along x or y direction?

Tags: opencv, gradient

If I find the gradient of an image using OpenCV and store the x-gradient in matrix X and y-gradient in matrix Y, by just looking at the images X and Y, is there any way to tell if the gradient is along x or y axes?

Visually, will I be able to detect any difference between the two images?

Comment: It's rather hard to know what some unspecified code might do to an unseen image... it would help if you showed both.

Comment: I didn't run any code. It was something that I was asked and I didn't know the answer. If there were no captions for the cat images on this page- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_gradient, would there be any way to say which image shows x gradient and y gradient?

Comment: Well, a horizontal gradient is going to find vertical edges because, if you think about it, if you pass across a vertical edge from left to right there will be changes as you go, whereas if you travel up or down along a vertical edge there will be no changes. It's kind of like cliffs - walk along them and there is no change, but walk perpendicular to a cliff and something bad's gonna happen. Likewise, a vertical gradient will tend to highlight horizontal edges. HTH.